# How create a Noninstantiable class java?

Tags: java

```
public class CarServices { 
  private CarServices() { } // Prevents instantiation

 //some methods

}
```

I prevent the constructor from been instantiated is this the correct way, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that is a common way to prevent instantiation.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare It's not a singleton if it is never instantiated.

Comment: ignoring the fact that a "non instantiable class" does not make any sense in an OO language in the first place (no not even for "utility classes") you need to make the class `abstract` so that it cannot be instantiated from itself.

Comment: Well, an inner class can still instance it (like a `Builder` implemented in this class)

Answer (score 2):

You can mark your class - abstract:

```
public abstract class CarService{
...
}
```

We can't create instance for abstract class, only extends for this class.